# Swift cannot specialize generic parameter when the specializing type is constrained with additional protocol

Tags: swift

Imagine the following scenario:

```swift
class Food {}

protocol Growable {}

class Animal<T: Food> {}

let animal1 = Animal<Food>() // Ok
let animal2 = Animal<Food & Growable>() // Compile error: 'Animal' requires that 'Food & Growable' inherit from 'Food'
```

Clearly, if we have a variable of type `Food & Growable`, this variable is also of type `Food`. Yet the generic Parameter `T` of the `Animal` class can't be specialized with the type `Food & Growable`. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is a bit strange but what you are trying to do is invalid.

You cannot create generics using protocols. When creating a generic, you have to use a *concrete type*. Not a protocol.

`Food & Growable` is not a *concrete type*.

You would need a subclass:

```
class GrowableFood: Food, Growable {
   ...
}

let animal2 = Animal<GrowableFood>()
```

or, you can extend `Animal` if `Food` is `Growable`:

```
extension Animal where T: Growable {
}
```